# Magento 1.9: How to translate TITLES and TITLES OPTIONS of the "Custom Options" of simple products?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, importexport, massaction, attribute-options

I need to translate all the TITLES and OPTION TITLES of the Custom Options related to simple Magento products.
The need is:
1- Export all the fields of the "custom Option"
2- Translate them (or how to modify them)
3- Import them into the desired shop view.

I am already working with mass exports / imports throughout the catalog using the "attribute codes" of Magento attributes, including customized ones, by exporting from "Dataflow" and choosing which attributes to export. All these attributes are available from the Magento Backend: Catalog / Attributes / Attribute management> List of all attributes.
And therefore selectable in "dataflow".

But those of the "CUSTOM OPTIONS" are not present !!
How then can we export those present in the base shop, and subsequently import them?

I have been looking for a lot of absolution, but still nothing.
thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your point. Everything on backend can be translate via:

Store > configuration > advanced > developer > translate inline > enabled for admin

Refresh the page, clock over texts you want to translate, clear cash

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for rating. I have many many points to translate, I need strength to export, work on an external file and then update everything en masse! Do you have any idea? Thank you